# HostnameVerifier vs TrustManager?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jsse

Under what circumstances would one use a `HostnameVerifier` over a `TrustManager` in Java? Is one recommended over the other? Looking at the Java docs ([Interface HostnameVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html) and [Interface TrustManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html)), I can't tell when its best to use either (though the `TrustManager` seems more versatile).

In the past, I have always used a custom `TrustManager`. However, I noticed [Heartbleed exploit in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571736/heartbleed-exploit-in-java) uses both (but I don't think its correct).

**EDIT**: when using `HostnameVerifier`, are the other customary X509 checks performed, like path building and expiration and revocation (if configured)? I think I am essentially asking if `HostnameVerifier` supplements the other checks (rather than replacing them).

For example, suppose a dev server is at `dev.example.com` and its signed by an internal CA. There's one DNS name in `dev.example.com`'s certificate, and its `dev.example.com`. Further, suppose I connect to it as `192.168.1.10`. Could I use a `HostnameVerifier` to allow both `dev.example.com` and `192.168.1.10`? In this scenario, is the additional name allowed *and* are the other customary X509 checks are performed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Under what circumstances would one use a HostnameVerifier over a TrustManager in Java?

Never. They do different things. TrustManage authenticates certificates as part of SSL. HostnameVerifier verifies host names as part of HTTPS. They're not in competition.

> Is one recommended over the other?

No.

**EDIT**

- The `TrustManager` runs during the TLS handshake. If it indicates failure, the handshake is aborted and the connect fails.
- The `HostnameVerifier` runs *after* the TLS handshake, over a TLS connection that is already valid from the TLS point of view, so at that point you know that the certificate is valid, signed by a trusted issuer, non-expired (?), etc., and all you have to do is decide (a) whether it's from the correct server and (b) whether you trust that server. You might do (b) inside a `TrustManager,` but far more commonly you wouldn't provide your own `TrustManager` at all.

Comment: Thanks EJP. So I'm clear: a `TrustManager` cannot be used to override a hostname mismatch in `checkServerTrusted`?

Comment: @jww I didn't say that. I said there is no circumstance in which you would prefer one over the other. TrustManager is part of TLS; HostnameVerifier is part of HTTPS. They're not in competition. You can verify hostnames in a TrustManager if you need to: see the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html#checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.Socket)), but you're doing so for a different reason, under a different RFC, and at a different phase of the communication.

Comment: More detailed explanation: https://op-co.de/blog/posts/java_sslsocket_mitm/#index2h2

Comment: @FD_ JSSE implements RFC 2246 and successors, which at the time of implementing had no requirement for hostname verification. SSL/TLS only ever undertook to provide message secrecy+integrity and authentication. Authorization was always up to the application layer, in this case HTTP. The design still seems perfectly sensible to me even after 18 years.